# grouping datatable based on uptrend, downtrend and range in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like this :

```
timestamp           Value
05-01-2020  12:07:08    8
05-01-2020  12:36:05    9
05-01-2020  23:45:02    10.3
05-01-2020  13:44:33    11
06-01-2020  01:07:08    12.5
06-01-2020  10:23:05    11.3
06-01-2020  12:11:08    10.8
06-01-2020  22:06:12    9.7
07-01-2020  00:01:05    9.3
07-01-2020  02:17:09    8.6
07-01-2020  12:36:05    8.3
07-01-2020  12:07:08    7.8
07-01-2020  12:36:05    8.7
07-01-2020  12:36:05    9.3
08-01-2020  12:36:05    9.8
08-01-2020  12:36:05    10.4
08-01-2020  12:36:05    10.5
09-01-2020  12:36:05    10.3
09-01-2020  12:07:08    9.6
09-01-2020  12:36:05    9.1
11-01-2020  12:07:08    8.8
11-01-2020  12:36:05    8.3
```

I am trying to create three groups `G1,G2,G3`
`G1` is for uptrend(increasing order) for values `9 to 12` - Both values included,
`G2` is for downtrend(decreasing order) for values `12 to 9`  - Both values included,
`G3` is for range of values between `9 and 12`  - Both values included.

Grouping should be per day basis.

I am able to get `G3`. But other conditions are not working.

```
df[, G3 := rleid((value >= 9  & value <=12)  & (as.IDate(timestamp) == shift(as.Idate(timestamp),type ='lag'))]
```

Desired output :

```
timestamp              Value    G1  G2  G3
05-01-2020  12:07:08    8        1  1   1
05-01-2020  12:36:05    9        2  1   2
05-01-2020  23:45:02    10.3     2  1   2
05-01-2020  13:44:33    11       2  1   2
06-01-2020  01:07:08    12.5     3  1   3
06-01-2020  10:23:05    11.3     4  2   4
06-01-2020  12:11:08    10.8     4  2   4
06-01-2020  22:06:12    9.7      4  2   4
07-01-2020  00:01:05    9.3      5  3   5
07-01-2020  02:17:09    8.6      6  4   6
07-01-2020  12:36:05    8.3      6  4   6
07-01-2020  12:07:08    7.8      6  4   6
07-01-2020  12:36:05    8.7      6  4   6
07-01-2020  12:36:05    9.3      7  4   7
08-01-2020  12:36:05    9.8      8  4   8
08-01-2020  12:36:05    10.4     8  4   8
08-01-2020  12:36:05    10.5     8  4   8
09-01-2020  12:36:05    10.3     9  5   8
09-01-2020  12:07:08    9.6      9  5   9
09-01-2020  12:36:05    9.1      9  5   9
11-01-2020  12:07:08    8.8      9  6   10
11-01-2020  12:36:05    8.3      9  6   10
```

Comment: Ok I will update now

Comment: It is a mistake in data entry

Comment: hmm you might want to check your desired output carefully. seems like quite a number do not match what you described including G3

Comment: What about now ?

Comment: G1 rows 8 and 9 are on different dates

Comment: Yes I understood. i will correct it now..sorry

Comment: done..Please check

Comment: Still getting diff with your data and description. are u looking for `DT[, G1 := rleid(date, c(between(value[1L], 9, 12), diff(value)>0))][, G2 := rleid(date, c(between(value[1L], 9, 12), diff(value)<0))][, G3 := rleid(date, between(value, 9, 12))]` ?

Comment: What is this `value[1L]`  and why not used in `G3`?

Comment: first element of value. G3 is based on your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer to this interesting question.

It is difficult to judge if this answer is correct as the expected result posted in the question seems to be inconsistent even with OP's own rule set and with OP's own code (e.g., some day changes are not accounted for).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Date := as.IDate(timestamp, "%d-%m-%Y")]
df[, Change := nafill(c(diff(Value), NA), "locf"), by = Date]
df[, `:=`(
  G1 = rleid(Date, between(Value, 9, 12) & Change > 0),
  G2 = rleid(Date, between(Value, 9, 12) & Change < 0),
  G3 = rleid(Date, between(Value, 9, 12)),
  Date = NULL, 
  Change = NULL
)][]
```

> ```
>               timestamp Value G1 G2 G3
>  1: 05-01-2020 12:07:08   8.0  1  1  1
>  2: 05-01-2020 12:36:05   9.0  2  1  2
>  3: 05-01-2020 23:45:02  10.3  2  1  2
>  4: 05-01-2020 13:44:33  11.0  2  1  2
>  5: 06-01-2020 01:07:08  12.5  3  2  3
>  6: 06-01-2020 10:23:05  11.3  3  3  4
>  7: 06-01-2020 12:11:08  10.8  3  3  4
>  8: 06-01-2020 22:06:12   9.7  3  3  4
>  9: 07-01-2020 00:01:05   9.3  4  4  5
> 10: 07-01-2020 02:17:09   8.6  4  5  6
> 11: 07-01-2020 12:36:05   8.3  4  5  6
> 12: 07-01-2020 12:07:08   7.8  4  5  6
> 13: 07-01-2020 12:36:05   8.7  4  5  6
> 14: 07-01-2020 12:36:05   9.3  5  5  7
> 15: 08-01-2020 12:36:05   9.8  6  6  8
> 16: 08-01-2020 12:36:05  10.4  6  6  8
> 17: 08-01-2020 12:36:05  10.5  6  6  8
> 18: 09-01-2020 12:36:05  10.3  7  7  9
> 19: 09-01-2020 12:07:08   9.6  7  7  9
> 20: 09-01-2020 12:36:05   9.1  7  7  9
> 21: 11-01-2020 12:07:08   8.8  8  8 10
> 22: 11-01-2020 12:36:05   8.3  8  8 10
>               timestamp Value G1 G2 G3
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  "timestamp  time         Value
05-01-2020  12:07:08    8
05-01-2020  12:36:05    9
05-01-2020  23:45:02    10.3
05-01-2020  13:44:33    11
06-01-2020  01:07:08    12.5
06-01-2020  10:23:05    11.3
06-01-2020  12:11:08    10.8
06-01-2020  22:06:12    9.7
07-01-2020  00:01:05    9.3
07-01-2020  02:17:09    8.6
07-01-2020  12:36:05    8.3
07-01-2020  12:07:08    7.8
07-01-2020  12:36:05    8.7
07-01-2020  12:36:05    9.3
08-01-2020  12:36:05    9.8
08-01-2020  12:36:05    10.4
08-01-2020  12:36:05    10.5
09-01-2020  12:36:05    10.3
09-01-2020  12:07:08    9.6
09-01-2020  12:36:05    9.1
11-01-2020  12:07:08    8.8
11-01-2020  12:36:05    8.3")[
  , `:=`(timestamp = paste(timestamp, time), time = NULL)]
```